# Android: Custom Dialog displays on back navigation

Tags: android

The application displays a custom dialog by using the code `dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);` with in a `conditional statement` from `OnStart` method of a fragment.

But the issue is, after dismissing the fragment and navigate to any other `Activity` and click on back button displays the custom dialog again even the `conditional statement` is false.

How to suppress the dialog from being displayed.

Comment: plese update code. can you put the dialog in oncreate

Comment: @VV, still dialog displays after executing the code from `onCreate`.

Comment: please up date the code

Comment: The following are the exact code, 
if (InitialSettingDialog.isInitialSettingRequired()) {
   initialSettingDialog = InitialSettingDialog.getInstance();
   initialSettingDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
     InitialSettingDialog.TAG);
   InitialSettingDialog.listener = this;
  }
when the user clicks on back button the condition was evaluated to false, and the code did not executed, but the dialog was displayed. I follow the instruction of 'Arphan Sharm', it works and dialog did not appear.

Comment: that was my first comment

Comment: @VV, Only moving the code to `onCreate` did not worked on this scenario, but  calling the `dialog.dismiss()` from `onStop` and `onPause` make the dialog not appearing again. Please check the comments of that answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onStop and onPause dismiss the dialog by dialog.dismiss(). Make a global object of dialog. 
The reason is that you dialog is never dismissed and it stays in your activity so when you come back it is shown.

Comment: Calling `dialog.dismiss()` from `onStop` and `onPause` as per this answer resolved the issue.
But even before, the dialog was dismissed from the code with in the `DialogFragment` itself before navigating to any other activity, but dialog was still appearing on back navigation.

Comment: if the dialog was dismissed then the show function must have been called in the code. Otherwise the dialog can not reappear.

Comment: For experiment purpose, i revert back to my old code, and debug the application, 

1) The dialog was dismissed with in that `DialogFragment` derived class by calling `alertDialogObject.dismiss`
2) After navigating to another activity, clicking on back button, the dialog show method did not executed and `onCreateDialog` of `DialogFragment` derived class did not get called. but the Dialog was there.
 This is some what looks strange for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set your condition to false after dialog dismiss?

Comment: Yes, the condition became false after dialog displayed. When back button was clicked this condition checked and evaluated to false and dialog displaying code did not get executed but still dialog appears.